# Inline Code in ListView in ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I am trying to use a ASP.NET WebFroms ListView with inline code (for globalization, Frame.Article comes from an resx file):

```
      <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="demo" ItemType="Quarters<int>">
        <LayoutTemplate>
                    <strong><%# Frame.Article %></strong>                        
                    <strong><%# Frame.Customer %></strong>   
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />  
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <p><%# Item.Q1 %></p>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
 Quarters<int> quarter = new Quarters<int>();
 quarter.Q1 = 10;
 quarter.Q2 = 20;
 quarter.Q3 = 30;
 quarter.Q4 = 40;

 demo.DataSource = new List<Quarters<int>>(){quarter};
 demo.DataBind();
```

But I always get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView'
>   does not contain a definition for 'DataItem' and no extension method
>   'DataItem' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: What is Frame? Is it a class?

Comment: do you do something in the code behind?

Comment: Frame is a class that the resx file builds. So Frame.Article returns a string with a translation for the word "article".

Comment: @Izikon Yes, I create an sample object that bind it to the list.

Comment: 2 things: 1- if you remove the Frame class properties on the LayoutTemplate ,is it working. 2- if not 1, can you provide the codebehind code?

Comment: If I remove both frame statements it is working. If I write <strong><%# "Frame.Customer" %></strong>  it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this after experiencing the same problem. Posting answer here in case anyone does the same in future.

The cause is the data-binding expressions (e.g. `<%# Frame.Article %>`) within the `LayoutTemplate`. ASP.NET does not support data-binding expressions within such templates.

Simplest solution to specific problem above is to move those expressions out of the `ListView` template ie:

```
  <strong><%# Frame.Article %></strong>                        
  <strong><%# Frame.Customer %></strong> 
  <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="demo" ItemType="Quarters<int>">
    <LayoutTemplate>  
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />  
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Item.Q1 %></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```